# Alsa recording buffer stuck in a loop

Tags: audio-recording, alsa

I'm trying to write a program to visualize recorded samples using ALSA. This is how I set the parameters:

```
if ((rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) <     0)
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "device not opened (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
fs = 16000;
channels = 1;

if ((rc = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc(&params)) < 0) 
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "harware parameter structure not allocated (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
if ((rc = snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params)) < 0) 
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "hardware parameter structure not set (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
if ((rc = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0) 
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "access type not set (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
if ((rc = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params,SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)) < 0) 
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "sample format not set (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }       
if ((snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params,channels)) < 0) 
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "cannot set channel count (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
 if ((rc = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near (handle, params, &fs, 0)) < 0) 
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "sample rate not set (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
frames = 256;

if ((rc = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle,params, &frames, &dir)) < 0) 
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "period size not set (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
{
               fprintf (stderr, "parameters weren't set into the driver (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
if ((rc = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames,&dir)) < 0) 
    {
               fprintf (stderr, "cannot get period size (%s)\n",
           snd_strerror (rc));
                exit (1);
                    }
size = frames * 2; 

if     (channels==1)
        size = frames * 2;  
else if(channels==2)
        size=frames*2*2;    
cache = (signed short int *) malloc(size);
```

And this is the actual loop for recording:

```
while(1)
{


MAXINT = 32768.0;

if ((err = snd_pcm_wait (handle, 1000)) < 0) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "poll failed (%s)\n", strerror (errno));
                    break;
        }


if ((err = snd_pcm_readi(handle,cache,frames)) < 0){

                     cerr<<"error"<<endl;
                     break;
        }

for (int i=0;i<frames;i++)

{

   double cache_norm = cache[i]/MAXINT;
   emit samples(cache_norm);

}



}
```

What I am trying to do is read 256 frames and read the whole cache (buffer) frame by frame in a for loop. Then, I am using Qt library for viewing the recorded signal. I am also using a QThread library, that's why I am emitting the variable "samples".

However, the buffer seems to be stuck in a loop, it doesn't respond to any changes in recording. It emits only the same 256 frames over and over again. The situation changes when I put the function snd_pcm_readi(handle,cache,frames) inside the for loop. But I think that then I get only one sample from the whole frame. And I need all the samples. How can this be achieved?

I also need to check whether I did not loose any samples. Is there a function in ALSA for that?

One more thing I noticed is that my cache can only be 512 bytes long (it is allocated that way). However, It seems to get bigger (a lot bigger) when I'm trying to debug the code in Qt creator. How can it get bigger than allocated? Is there any explanation for that?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why the `snd_pcm_wait` call? Aren't you using blocking mode? `snd_pcm_readi` returns the number of read frames. How many channels?

Comment: I've done something like you but with C++11 thread (pthreads), have a look https://github.com/Waxo/ALSA_encapsulation